# How to change the font colour in html/rmarkdown?

Tags: html, r, text, r-markdown, tidyverse

I have some chunks in my rmarkdown with titles and comments. I wonder if it's possible to change the font colour of these texts in HTML output??

`````
### Title
```{r}

````
comment
`````

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS/HTML styling to colour. Here is an example:

`````
---
title: "test"
ouput: html_document
---

### Title
```{r}

````
comment

Here is some text, <p style="color:yellow">this part of which is yellow!</p>
`````

Output:

[image]